# Typescript Prepend a string in a type

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if there is a way to prepend a string in a type, I have an api that the sort is [key] for ascending, and -[key] for descending

This works, but does not allow the -[key]

```
export interface IJsonAPI<T extends Record<string, any>> {
  filter?: Record<keyof T, IJsonAPIFilters>;
   sort?: Array<keyof T>;
}
```